# image.jpg instead of true.html in save dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to add image in my snippet code but hope the question will bi clear anyway.

Want to save i.e. download `imgb` on disk.

`Save As` dialog appears but:

- default name and format is `true.html` - I want it to be `image.jpg` or similar.
- there is no any existing image in the list so I can't click and replace it with the new one.
- if I write `image.jpg` inside `Save As` dialog the final result is not an image but a black rectangle.

Any help?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  let dl = document.createElement("a");
  dl.href = document.getElementById('imgb');
  dl.download = true;
  document.body.appendChild(dl);
  dl.click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='imgb' id='imgb' src='img.jpg' alt='img'>
<br><br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
 $('button').on('click', function(){
      let dl = document.createElement("a");
      dl.href = document.getElementById('imgb').getAttribute("src");
      dl.download = true;
      document.body.appendChild(dl);
      dl.click();
    });
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

html:

```
    <img id='imgb' src='img.jpg' alt='img'>
    <br><br>
    <button>CLICK</button>
```

Your element hat the class of imgb and not id, and you can access the href by using getAtribute

Comment: document.getElementById('imgb').getAttribute("src") try with src